# Using mod_rewrite with Zend Framework to remove "public" from my URL

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite

For some reason I get public in my url like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/public/

This should be the index page so how do I get rid of the public so it just reads:

http://www.mywebsite.com/

I tried adjusting .htaccess, vhost and everything, not sure what to do here...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.* -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: what happens when you goto `http://www.mywebsite.com/` and what is your directory structure.

Comment: I have a html index page in place until i figure this out. The directory is public_html and the html index sits outside of the rest of the directory.. other than that basic zframework directory stuffs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your apache Virtual Host configuration. I bet it is looking at /home/yourdomain.com instead of /home/yourdomain.com/public (or similar).

Comment: my vhost looks at Apache2/htdocs/mysite/root. I tried pointing it to public but no real change

Comment: @user154107: After changing virtual host setting, always restart your apache server.

Comment: That's your problem. It needs to look at Apache2/htdocs/mysite/root/public

Then like NAVEED said, restart or reload apache for settings to take effect.